# How can i use extended attributes for file tagging in ubuntu desktop in a pratical way?

Tags: files, filesystem, directory, tagging

I was wondering why there is no graphical implementation of xattr in ubuntu desktop. In my opinion tagging files and folders with extended attributes is a quite convenient way to organize data.

Does someone uses extended attribute for this kind of purpose or is there a better way? For me it looks like xattr is not very common. Through a quick web search I couldn't find much information about it and I actually wondering why.
I know it depends on the filesystem, lets assume we talk about EXT4.

I would be pleased if someone could help me out.

Comment: I've been considering xattr for file tagging, since it seems far better than a couple of my own solutions.  On my system, apparently, xattr are added for downloaded files by either the system or Google Chrome, which is what I use. Otherwise, I've not heard of any GUI tools for that so far.

Comment: @Sergiy Did you check caja?

Comment: @S.V. Caja ? I think i have heard about it but never used. What about it ?